# Function that modify text on lists push the last element out of the list

Tags: list, vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have this procedure to add "`<OK>`" to red colored elements on a list, but it push the elements that are last of its lists

```
Sub Rojo()
    Dim lista As Integer
    Dim para As Paragraph

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.ListParagraphs
        If para.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed Then
            para.Range.Text = "<OK> " + para.Range.Text
        End If
    Next para
```

The if I have list:

- black text
- black text
- Red Text
- Red text

It becomes:

- black text
- black text
- `<OK>`Red Text

Red text<--This is pushed out of the list

What shoudl I do?

Answer (score 0):

Adde this and elements becomes listed again, but on a new list. Now I would need to push it into the former list. (Hecho is a global boolean)

```
       Sub Rojo()

Dim p As Paragraph

Dim iTotalParas As Integer, iParaCounter As Integer
Comienzo:
If hecho = False Then
    iTotalParas = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    For iParaCounter = 1 To iTotalParas
'    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

            Set p = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(iParaCounter)
            If p.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed Then
                        'Mi cosecha
                        p.Range.Text = "<OK>" + p.Range.Text
                        If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(iParaCounter).Range.ListFormat.ListType = 0 Then
                            ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(iParaCounter).Range.ListFormat.ApplyOutlineNumberDefault

                        End If

            End If

'    Next p
    Next iParaCounter
    hecho = True
   'Si ya la hemos ejecutado y volvemos a usarla, avisa antes y controlamos la repetición
    Else
        If MsgBox("Ya has ejecutado esta macro boniato!" & Chr(13) & "¿Quieres ejecutarla de nuevo?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbYes Then
            hecho = False
            GoTo Comienzo
        Else
            hecho = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

EDITED:::::::::========
Ok, the more I do with this, the more I learn. Ionly had to change p.Range.Text = "" + p.Range.Text to p.Range.InsertBefore("OK")

Comment: I'm still waiting for someone to help me please XDDD